# How to download 5000 Cropped Images From GEE with Dynamic Names?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, imagery, download, dynamic

I have a CSV dataset where 5000 sat image data has been given lat, long, path, row, Date, and Landsat Name. I want to filter out images using date, path, row. Cropped out a 27*27 patch centered around given lat, and long and download the cropped to Google Drive image with  an Id as its name.

Up to cropping of image is completed but Exporting of image creates problem as it is not taking the Id variable value into the Export.Image.toDrive.

```
/**** Start of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. ****/
var imageCollection7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2"),
imageCollection8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2"),
imageCollection5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2"),
table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-soma-mitra/assets/AquaSat_Shorten2");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
var myCSV = ee.FeatureCollection(table);

var EndDate = myCSV.aggregate_array('EndDate');
var StartDate = myCSV.aggregate_array('StartDate');
var ID = myCSV.aggregate_array('ID');
var path= myCSV.aggregate_array('path');
var row = myCSV.aggregate_array('row');
var lat = myCSV.aggregate_array('lat');
var long = myCSV.aggregate_array('long');
var LandsatCollection= myCSV.aggregate_array('LandsatCollection');
var i;
for(i=0;i<5000;i++)
{
 var imageId=ee.String(ID.get(i));
 var imageED=ee.String(EndDate.get(i));
 var imageSD=ee.String(StartDate.get(i));
 var imageLC=ee.String(LandsatCollection.get(i));
 var imagePath=ee.Number(path.get(i)) ;
 var imageRow = ee.Number(row.get(i));
 var imageLat = ee.Number(lat.get(i));
 var imageLong = ee.Number(long.get(i));
 var image ;
 //var filename = Number.format(ID.get(i));
 //print(filename);
 print(imageLC);
 print(imageRow);
 print(imagePath);
 var image=ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(imageLC.compareTo('LT05').eq(0),imageCollection5
                                                                              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',imagePath))
                                                                              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', imageRow))
                                                                              .filterDate(imageSD,imageED)
                                                                              .select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7']).first(),
                            ee.Algorithms.If(imageLC.compareTo('LE07').eq(0),imageCollection7
                                                                             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',imagePath))
                                                                             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', imageRow))
                                                                             .filterDate(imageSD,imageED)
                                                                             .select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7']).first(),
                                                                             imageCollection8
                                                                             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',imagePath))                                                                            
                                                                             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', imageRow))
                                                                             .filterDate(imageSD,imageED)
                                                                             .select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7']).first()
                    )));

    
  //print(image.id().getInfo()); 
 // print(image.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"]);
var region=ee.Geometry.Point([imageLong, imageLat]).buffer(390);
  
  var polygonBounds = region.bounds();
  print(polygonBounds);
var croppedAndClippedImage = image.clip(polygonBounds);
//print(croppedAndClippedImage.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"]);
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: croppedAndClippedImage,
    folder:'Dataset',
    //fileNamePrefix: filename+"_",
    description: imageId, // Choose a descriptive name
    scale: 30, // Optional: Set the desired export resolution
    //region: region // Specify the region to export
  });
  


}
```